# multiple AVL tree rotation

Tags: data-structures, rotation, avl-tree

Say i have a unordered set s{3,6,5,1,2,4} and i need to construct an AVL tree,
 
this much is fine... i understand basic rotations and i get to this point here:

```
                               5 
                             /   \
                            2      6
                           / \
                         1     3
```

but it all falls apart when i try to insert 4
and i get my final answer as (the left one)

```
             4      But the actual answer is:      3
           /   \                                 /   \
          2     5                               2     5
         / \     \                             /     / \
        1   3     6                           1     4   6
```

And when i break it down i get stuck doing the same rotation
so im asking how do i do a rotation with the parent that is valid for this AVL?

and is my solution valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as I understand it, when you first add 4 you get the following tree.

```
    5
   / \
  2   6
 / \
1   3
     \
      4
```

To follow along, refer to [Wikipedia's article on AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree). Because the *balance factor* (note that this is defined in the article) of node 5 is +2 and the balance factor of node 2 is -1, you first need to rotate the node 2 subtree left.

```
      5
     / \
    3   6
   / \
  2   4
 /
1
```

Next, you need to rotate the entire tree right (about node 5).

```
    3
   / \
  2   5
 /   / \
1   4   6
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: ahh i see, i was calculating the balance factor out wrong, Thanks.

Comment: Can we consider that we have to recalculate balance factor, from newly added node to root path only ? or need to Check for entire tree.

Comment: @Milan As I understand it, you start at the inserted node and check the balance factor for each of its parents. If you encounter a balance factor of ±2, rebalance that node's subtree; if you encounter a balance factor of ±1, continue to the next parent; if you encounter a balance factor of 0 or the root, stop.

Comment: @ChrisFrederick If balance is ±2 factor then I have to rebalance sub tree (also parent tree if required), Now balancing sub tree means two rotation (LR or RL)  only or there can be more than two rotation in that subtree ?