# Can someone explain me this kind of recursion?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, pseudocode

I want to understand recursion.
I understand stupid example with math but i m not sure to know the essence of it.

I have 1 example that i don t understand how it works:

```
TREE-ROOT-INSERT(x, z)

if x = NIL
   return z
if z.key < x.key
   x.left = TREE-ROOT-INSERT(x.left, z)
   return RIGHT-ROTATE(x)
else 
   x.right = TREE-ROOT-INSERT(x.right, z)
   return LEFT-ROTATE(x)
```

I know what this code does:
First insert a node in a BST and then rotate each time so the new node became the root.

But in my mind analysing the code i suppose that it insert the node where it has to go and then JUST 1 TIME it rotates the tree.

How is it possible that the tree is rotated every time?

Comment: This might be a better example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323656/multiple-avl-tree-rotation?rq=1

Comment: Also this example here *insertion of 15* suggests more than one rotation might be needed https://jriera.webs.ull.es/Docencia/avl_handout.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain your place in the recursive call for each level of the tree. When you hit `return RIGHT-ROTATE` (or left) for the first time, you're not completely done; you take the tree that is the result of the `ROTATE` function, and place it in the code where the recursive `TREE-ROOT-INSERT` call was one level higher in the stack. You then rotate again, and return the current tree one level higher up in the stack, until you've hit the original root of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

What is important for understanding recursion is to think of the recursive function as an **abstract black box**. In other words, when reading or reasoning about recursive function, you should focus on the current iteration, treat the invocation of the recursive function as atomic (something you cannot explore into) assuming it can do what it is supposed to do, and see how its result can be used to solve the current iteration.

You already know the contract of your `TREE-ROOT-INSERT(x, z)`:

*insert z into a binary search tree rooted at x, transform the tree so that z will become the new root.*

let's look at this snippet:

```
   if z.key < x.key
      x.left = TREE-ROOT-INSERT(x.left, z)
      return RIGHT-ROTATE(x)
```

This says z is less than x so it goes to the left sub-tree (because it is BST). `TREE-ROOT-INSERT` is invoked again, but we won't follow into it. Instead we just assume it can do what it is meant to do: it will insert z to the tree rooted at x.left, and make z the new root. Then you will get a tree of the bellow structure:

```
     x
    / \
   z  ...
  / \
... ...
```

Again, you don't know how exactly calling `TREE-ROOT-INSERT(x.left, z)` will get you the z-rooted sub-tree. At this moment you don't care, because the real important part is what follows: how to make this entire tree rooted at z? The answer is the `RIGHT-ROTATE(x)`

> But in my mind analysing the code i suppose that it insert the node where it has to go and then JUST 1 TIME it rotates the tree.
>
> How is it possible that the tree is rotated every time?

If I understand you correctly, you are still thinking how to solve the problem in a non-recursive way. It is true that you can insert z into the BST rooted at x using the standard BST insertion procedure. That will put z in the correct position. However to bring z to the root from that position, you need more than 1 rotation.

In the recursive version, rotation is required to bring z to the root after you get a z-rooted sub-tree. But to get the z-rooted sub-tree from the original x.left rooted sub-tree, you need a rotation as well. Rotation is called many times, but on different sub-trees.